# Can I use -ing in "have to" show a compulsion in present continuous?

Tags: modal-verbs, present-continuous

We use 'have to' to express a compulsion in the present, like "I have to speak English." For past we use "I had to speak English."

For the present continuous can we say "I am having to speak English"?

Comment: For a compulsion, you could say, "I feel a need to..." or "I feel an overwhelming urge to ...."

Answer (score 1):

It is a grammatically correct use of the present continuous, but it really does not sound very fluent.  I would recommend that you not use this phrasing.  Just say "I have to _____".

"I am ____ing" expresses my current state; for example, "I am eating" means that is what I am doing right now; my current state is "eating".  But "I have to ____" already expresses something about my state, namely that I am in a condition of needing to do something, so it doesn't really make sense to say, effectively, "My current state is being in a state of needing to _____."

The only time I would ever say "I am having to ____" is maybe if I wanted to express that it was an ongoing condition, or if it were necessary to specify my condition at the moment as opposed to in general.  For example, "I'm always having to correct Michael's grammar" meaning not that I have to correct his grammar right now, but that it is a recurrent or ongoing "have to".  Or for another example, "Right now I'm having to work really hard just to stay awake."